# What should I do with a duplicate for which the flag aged away? Should the other question then become the duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, exact-duplicates

I marked:

- [Disk usage at 100% during startup](https://superuser.com/q/1769435/1192848)

  - +16
  - Asked 10 months ago
  - Modified 10 months ago
  - Viewed 14k times
  - 6 answers: +23, +11, +9, +3, +2, +1

as a duplicate of:

- [Disk usage is always at 100%](https://superuser.com/q/1044707/1192848)

  - +1
  - Asked 7 years, 10 months ago
  - Modified 5 days ago
  - Viewed 5k times
  - 1 answer: +2 (my answer from December 2022, thus answered only after almost 7 years)

And the flag aged away.

I marked it as a duplicate since I had the same question in December 2022, and then, the younger question was not yet asked. At that time, I did thorough research and found the question that was 7 years old. Even though I knew that this is very old, it was still the same that I had.
Now in February 2023, someone did not make such a research and opened a highly active question. It stresses more the startup time, but I guess that this goes without saying since I had it also at startup, but not always just 15-20 minutes but also half an hour or two hours. Asking about this being always at 100 % is a shortened way of saying that this lagging begins with the startup and lasts a long time.

I would like to mark the younger and higher active question as the duplicate of the older one, and since the flag aged away, I wonder how the community sees this. Does the older question have the "right" to put a duplicate marker on a younger question, or is the higher activity of the younger question proof enough that the old question is not found well on the net and should become the duplicate of the younger question instead?

How does the community deal with a duplicate for which the flag aged away:

- Should the older question then become the duplicate?
- Should I try to flag the younger question as a duplicate again?

Comment: General comment: an older question can definitely be marked as a duplicate of a younger question, odd as that might seem at first. Generally it's worth doing if there's a compelling reason to- ie the newer question is 'better' somehow (more general / more varied answers etc)

Comment: Aging away means that not enough people were able to check your flag fast enough, most of the time. Or, more rarely, that there was indecision, which I don't think is the case here. Trying the same action e.g. a month later could work.

Comment: Embarrassing for me, I have switched the duplicate with the duplicated question in those first two blocks at the beginning. Now it is right: the question here is about closing the younger question as a duplicate of the older. Else, I would have marked the older question as a duplicate rightaway. I guess that the answer to this meta question is that I will have to make the old question a duplicate of the younger question, but I wait for more remarks or answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second flag aged away as well.

- I guess that this shows that you should ask a new question on top of the same old one next time if the old question is 7 years old. If it is that old, nobody thinks that it might still be the same, during search. I was also astonished:

  > It seems unbelievable, but this is a known issue even seven years
  > later, I have also had a computer with this problem since a year, now
  > end of 2022, never took the time to fix it though.

  But it does not help the searchers who will check how old a question is, and perhaps also the search machines that might have algorithms for that.
- The older question was also not asked so well. It was in the remarks that it should be written clearer and needed to be edited. The asker was new on the Stack Exchange.
- The older question also did not stress that it is mainly at startup. "Disk usage at 100% during startup" is clearer about that than "Disk usage is always at 100%" which is meant the same, since everytime you start the computer, it is at 100%, and for my computer, it sometimes did not even stop after hours if I ran it after a long time. Even if I have the same problem, since normally, after an hour, it is not laggy anymore.
- Next time, I should check that a question fits best, not just quite a bit.
- And checking whether you should stick fully to the rules of finding duplicates is sometimes not the best way to go since for this question, there was not even an answer after 7 years, and from that, you can see that it was better to ask a new one.

That is why I flag the older answer now as a duplicate of the younger. Thus, the answer to the question "Should the other question then become the duplicate?" is "Yes".